# Easiest way to get API data into str/int format python

Tags: python, pandas, api, formatting

I have read through many articles and posts to connect to an api then format it into int/str however I did mange to make possibly the longest winded way ever its real ugly please could someone show me the shortest most efficient way to accomplish the below code any suggestions would be greatly appreciated bassically looking to print out "eos" in str format and "price" as int Thanks!

```
import urllib
import json

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/eos/')

with open('events.csv','w') as fd:
    fd.write(r.text)

data = pd.read_csv('events.csv', names=['Choose One'])

i = data.iloc[[6], [0]]

a = str(i)

name,price = a.split(":")

string = price[2:-1]

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to just use pandas `read_json` to read the file into a data frame, read_json will automatically assign the apt datatype to each column, then use column selection to select 'name','price_usd' columns (of-course in this case there is only one row, but the same code can be used with multiple rows)

i.e.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/eos/')

print(df[['name','price_usd']].apply(lambda row:'{}: {:.0f}'.format(ro
w['name'],row['price_usd']),axis=1))
```

using .0f in the format statement will display the integer part (rounded) of the price_usd value so the output will be.

```
0    EOS: 9
```

alternatively using the round function will round the float values 
i.e.

```
In [34]: import pandas as pd
    ...: df = pd.read_json('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/eos/')
    ...: print(df[['name','price_usd']].apply(lambda row:'{}: {:}'.format(row['n
    ...: ame'],round(row['price_usd'],2)),axis=1))
    ...: 
    ...: 
0    EOS: 8.99
```

dtype: object

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `json.loads(r.text)` or much easier directly `r.json()`.

Say, right now the api returns the following data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "eos", 
        "name": "EOS", 
        "symbol": "EOS", 
        "rank": "9", 
        "price_usd": "9.31992", 
        "price_btc": "0.00106154", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "596467000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "6034993504.0", 
        "available_supply": "647537050.0", 
        "total_supply": "900000000.0", 
        "max_supply": "1000000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "1.3", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-6.81", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-36.4", 
        "last_updated": "1517755757"
    }
]
```

If you use `r.json()`, you get this as a json, otherwise load it with `data = json.loads(r.text)` and save it to a pandas DataFrame with `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` which then looks like the following:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
  24h_volume_usd available_supply   id last_updated market_cap_usd    max_supply name percent_change_1h percent_change_24h percent_change_7d   price_btc price_usd rank symbol total_supply
0    596467000.0      647537050.0  eos   1517755757   6034993504.0  1000000000.0  EOS               1.3              -6.81             -36.4  0.00106154   9.31992    9    EOS  900000000.0
```

Access the data with pandas indexing:

```
In [8]: df[['name', 'price_usd']]
Out[8]:
  name price_usd
0  EOS   9.29186
```

Or for printing:

```
In [18]: print df.loc[0, 'name'], ': ', df.loc[0, 'price_usd']
EOS :  9.31992
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot not having to save it as a CSV what a waste of time! This looks nice and easy thanks!